# Can I "put" a file directly into a perforce depot?

Tags: bash, perforce

In my current process I use a perl (though this could be bash too) script to

- generate temporary files in a deep directory structure,
- then I add them to the repository
- then I submit them
- and finally I delete them locally, because I will never need them again (on the machine that runs the script)

I was wondering: since the content of the files could be handled in memory, is there a way to just "put" the files directly into the repository?

What I am looking is something similar to doing

```
echo "foo bar baz" > //depot/a/really/deep/folder/structure/that/ends/in/afile.txt
```

in one step, avoiding all the temporary files cleanup etcetera.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. What is the link with your `perforce` repository ? Why do you need to put temp files into your repository ?

Comment: I believe your current approach is the best available. You should contact Perforce technical support. There is an open request for this functionality, and you can add your name to the list of requestors for it. Then they'll let you know when it gets implemented.